# Laravel many to many relationship with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have 4 tables `users, opportunities, level_translations and levels`

**users**
id, name, email

**opportunities**
id, client_name, user_id, total_price

**levels**
id, min, max

**level_translations**
id, name, description, locale, level_id

I want to get level name in current locale for given user id .. i'm using [laravel-translatable](https://github.com/dimsav/laravel-translatable) package to localize my application

to get level it should be something like this

```
select * from levels where sum(opportunities.total_price) < levels.max and sum(opportunities.total_price) > levels.min
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. my solution contain tow parts
**first part**
creating a [MYSQL Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html), i call it *sumUserOwnopportunities(USERID)*

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE  FUNCTION `sumUserWonOpportunities`(USERID INT) 
 RETURNS double
BEGIN
     DECLARE TOTAL_SUM DOUBLE DEFAULT 0;
     SELECT SUM(opportunities.total_price) from opportunities 
     WHERE opportunities.user_id=USERID AND (opportunities.status=1 OR opportunities.status=2) INTO TOTAL_SUM;
        RETURN TOTAL_SUM;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**second part**
in User model

```
function level(){
   return  Level::where(function ($q){
            $q->where("min","<",DB::raw(" sumUserWonOpportunities($this->id)"))
            ->where("max",">",DB::raw(" sumUserWonOpportunities($this->id)"));
        })->first();
}
```

now I can call

```
$user=User::find(1);
$level=$user->level()->name;// it will return level name in current locale
```

I hope this useful.